# variants in modern c++, what is the best way to do them

Tags: c++, windows, c++17

In going from a C paradigm to a modern C++ one, I am trying to figure out what the best C++ replacement might be for the way older-style COM or device represent variants: [PROPVARIANT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propidlbase/ns-propidlbase-propvariant), and [DEVPROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/drivers/dn315030(v%3Dvs.85)).

In the C sense, these variants are just a struct with: a key (GUID, PID pair), data type (which is just a UIN32), and a buffer.

```
typedef struct _DEVPROPERTY {
  DEVPROPCOMPKEY CompKey;
  DEVPROPTYPE    Type;
  ULONG          BufferSize;
  PVOID          Buffer;
} DEVPROPERTY, *PDEVPROPERTY;
```

With these, PnP and old Shell-type COM components can pass property data generically.

I know I can just reuse these C structs in c++, but how would one do this with modern c++?

I know there is the [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) which seems to be a good replacement for a union, but I don't think it helps with the type discovery.

There is also [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), which seems like a std::variant but without predefining the types.

In any case, am not sure how to payload and rediscover the data type directly with these.  I guess I could still just have a struct with the type defined as an enum, and use the std:variant instead of a union.

For example, I still need to be able to do something like this:

```
void DoSomething(DEVPROPERTY* prop)
{
    // assume we would be doing safe things with these pointers instead of directly derefing them and casting them :)
    switch (prop->Type) {
    case DEVPROP_TYPE_INT32:
        LONG val = *(LONG*)prop->Buffer;
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Using `std::visit` - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit.
 
A few options - the most elegant is arguably #4 using a bunch of lamdas.

Comment: I feel like templates with specialisations for each type would be the _most_ elegant. Unless of course you cannot change the interface.

Comment: There is no such thing as "modern C++ paradigm", `std::variant` and `std::any` are not fundamentally different from plain C PROPVARIANT, they just perform a bit of encapsulating hiding implementation details on how values an their type tags are actually stored and providing a bit of extra type safety.

Comment: That seems a little pedantic, but ok sure.  When I said "modern,"  I meant contemporary or more up-to-date style C++.  To me that means, recent versions of the C++ standard like C++11, or C++17 using their matching contemporary standard library.  Our internal compilers support most of the C++17 standard and already some features of the upcoming C++20.  I thought it would be understood that modern C++ implied not old versions like C++98, or ANSI C style code.

Comment: My question is more about what would Stroustrup do?  If you followed the spirit of the C++ core guidelines, what would that look like? http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/

I could write all of my new C++ code using a C style, we certainly have written a lot of code like that, but I would be missing a lot of the benefit of the new C++ features.

Comment: Maybe what you need is `std::get_if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) should generally be your go to answer for this sort of thing.  They provide type-safe access to the contained value, which a good ol' "type enum and `void*`" type variant cannot provide.

For example, the `DoSomething` function from your question could be written something like this:

```
// Bit of boilerplate for combining lambdas
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

void DoSomething(const std::variant<long, std::string>& prop)
{
    std::visit(
        overloaded {
            [](long lng) { /* do whatever */ },
            [](const std::string& strng) { /* do whatever */ }
        },
        prop
    )
}
```

The correct lambda will be called for whatever type is held in `prop`, and you'll get a compile-time error if `prop` can hold a type that isn't handled.  No casting pointers and no forgetting to add a new handler if a new property type is added.

---

`std::any` is much closer to a type-checked `void*` than it is to a variant.  While it provides some *runtime* protection against accessing its value as the wrong type, it cannot provide any *compile time* protections.

`std::variant` is akin to a C construct like this:

```
struct variant {
    enum {
        INT,
        STRING
    } type;
    union {
        int i;
        char* c;
    }
};
```

While `std::any` is more akin to a C construct like this:

```
struct any {
    char* type;
    void* value;
};
```